# Is it possible to run pytest across multiple projects with one command

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I have a project involving a number of AWS lambda functions where I want to run pytest at any level to execute the tests within the current directory and its subdirectories.

The structure is

```
/src
  /lambda-one
    lambda_handler.py
    __init__.py
    /test
       test_lambda_handler.py
      __init__.py
  /group-a
    /lambda-two
      lambda_handler.py
      __init__.py
      /test
         test_lambda_handler.py
         __init__.py
    /lambda-three
      lambda_handler.py
      __init__.py
      /test
         test_lambda_handler.py
         __init__.py
  /group-b
    /lambda-four
      lambda_handler.py
      __init__.py
      /test
         test_lambda_handler.py
         __init__.py
    /lambda-five
      lambda_handler.py
      __init__.py
      /test
         test_lambda_handler.py
         __init__.py
```

To run the tests I either have to change directory to the actual lambda or change my import paths to absolute paths from src.

Is there a way to have pytest run at each lambda level (without a shell script) so I can get a single set of results.

Comment: Maybe this counts as "a shell script", but the `-execdir` option to `find` probably makes this easy.

Comment: It does, but it also leads to multiple runs of pytests rather than a single set of results

Comment: @aaron I have same project structure mentioned in question. I'm trying to run all test cases written under tests folder of different lambda functions. For Example "tests" folder of  lambda_one and lambda_two functions contains test cases as test_lambda_one and test_lambda_two. I am trying to run both test cases at once.

Comment: @RJ_Singh Can you share a sample project on GitHub, since the question does not describe a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can configure it on pytest.ini. Here is some example.

I have this directory structure.

```
.
├── pytest.ini
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lambda_one
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── lambda_handler.py
    │   └── test
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── test_lambda_handler.py
    └── lambda_two
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── lambda_handler.py
        └── test
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test_lambda_handler.py
```

Inside pytest.ini, I put this configuration.

```
[pytest]
python_files = */test/*.py
```

And here is the result of running pytest command outside the `src/` directory.

```
$ pytest
============================================================== test session starts ===============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/imad/TheHumbleProgrammer/stackoverflow/pytest-multiple-projects, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: dash-1.20.0
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                

src/lambda_one/test/test_lambda_handler.py .                                                                                               [ 50%]
src/lambda_two/test/test_lambda_handler.py .                                                                                               [100%]

=============================================================== 2 passed in 0.02s ================================================================
```

Comment: Anytime @RJ_Singh